# How to change column order of Data & Time picker Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Question: As you know that framework doesnot allow datetime picker in datagridview. i want to change the order of date and time currently i am using a method AdjustColumnOrder() but it is just changing the order of predefined columns.  exception code is commented.

```
  private void AdjustColumnOrder()
            {
                metroGrid1.Columns["Column1"].DisplayIndex = 0;
               // metroGrid1.Columns["fromDate"].DisplayIndex = 1;
               // metroGrid1.Columns["toDate"].DisplayIndex = 2;
                metroGrid1.Columns["Column6"].DisplayIndex = 3;
                metroGrid1.Columns["Column5"].DisplayIndex = 4;
            }
```

Comment: Is the DGV binding to an object?  Change order in binding object.

Answer (score 0):

The framework does allow you to make custom column types. For column with a DateTimePicker specifically, there is a perfectly good example at MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells

If you want to alter the display format, you will need to experiment with it a bit, but otherwise it's good as it is.